# VNC on DigitalOcean 16.04 server gives me old Gnome desktop, not Unity

Tags: unity, gnome, vnc

I've followed https://www.linode.com/docs/applications/remote-desktop/install-vnc-on-ubuntu-16-04 on a fresh Digital Ocean 16.04 server install.

Instead of the Unity desktop, I see an old Gnome desktop with menus and no Unity bar.

Is the howto wrong?

How can I get the Unity desktop instead?

Comment: You are using gnome-panel and metacity in vnc config file. You need to change that to unity, unity-settings-daemon etc. Look at xsession files to know what other components are required. Unity doesn't really play well in vnc. So metacity session is probably better.

Comment: @KhurshidAlam Thanks, can I conclude that the howto is incorrect?  Do you have a reference to Unity not playing nicely with VNC?  (I use it a lot with my desktop machine, and haven't seen any issues yet.)  Make this an answer and I'll accept it.